# Set clickable areas over a background image

Tags: android, layout

I'm developing an Android 2.3.3 application that will work on **mobile** and **tablet** devices.

I have a main view with a background image. This image has buttons and other texts and I want to make a clickable area over those buttons. They are not real buttons, those buttons are part of the background image.

**How can I do that?**

Maybe I can use an `ImageButton` without image because I don't know how to set a button transparent.

Comment: In my mind only one option is put transparent buttons or images on clickable area over those buttons.

Comment: And make button transparent `android:src="@null"` or `android:src="@android:color/transparent"` .

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Framelayout as the click area and just use ImageView as an indicator.
For example :

```
    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/play_button_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/button_frame_colors">
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/play_button_indicator"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/button_indicator"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

create your custom ImageView, define regions (rects or coordinates) and listen for onTouch events and iterate trough your list when touch event occurs and react if user has touched a defined region

Answer (score 0):

You can also place a layout with no background. It will work for sure as you want.